# Add Web Part manually

Tags: web-part

I have SP site. It's written by editing Default.aspx. (I don't have possibility to edit templates). I have there several buttons and sliders. I need to add a web part in it. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you need to edit the page and add a web part to it without editing the page layout?

Comment: I need to add webpart without changing the layout of buttons, I've added via Default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Hit the edit-button

[image]

On the Insert tab, select Web Part (or App Part)

[image]

Select which web part to insert

[image]

Save the page

[image]

And your Web Part is on the page without changing anything else

[image]

Comment: How can i adjust position of web part? It lays under buttons.

Comment: @user3102962 You can manually resize web parts in its properties. you can also move it by typing text above or below or just by adding new lines.